# Razor RenderPage and PageData not working

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to razor and was following a tutorial putting together a super simple hello world type app. Each time I try to use PageData or RenderPage I get the following:

```
The name 'PageData' does not exist in the current context
+
        @{ if ((bool)PageData["ShowFooter"] == true)
The name 'RenderPage' does not exist in the current context
+
                @RenderPage("_footer.cshtml")
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something super simple, I just don't know what that would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I selected Web -> Asp.Net core -> Web App (MVC)

Comment: Can you share the tutorial you are following? I don't see even similar options in ASP.NET Core nor ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. Either the tutorial is very old or it is not for ASP.NET Core

Comment: This is what I have been looking through:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look

Down towards the bottom there is a "PageData["ShowList"] example that I've been trying to tweak

Comment: Ahhh, so you are following an extremely old tutorial indeed. Look at the "software versions" part, it says "ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) 3". That's the old mix between ASP.NET WebForms and MVC. Either create a new ASP.NET Web Pages (warning: OLD, DEPRECATED) project or get a ASP.NET Core Razor Pages tutorial

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thank you, that makes sense. I'll look for other ways to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer will help, but I thought to share my idea because I ran into the same issue.
Because I could not render page I created for js scripts on the first start of the application, I used a tag called **partial** to render my cshtml page

```
<partial name="~/wwwroot/assets/scripts.cshtml" />
```